# Rust calling FnMut within implemented Struct

Tags: rust

i have the following code snippet which implements some kind of Emitter Struct:

```rust
type Callback<'a> = Option<&'a mut dyn FnMut()>;

struct Emitter<'a> {
  cb: Callback<'a>
}

impl<'a> Emitter<'a> {

  fn emit(&mut self) {
    if self.cb.is_some() {
      let f = self.cb.unwrap();
      f()
    }
  }
}

fn main() {

  let mut cb = || println!("test");

  let mut e = Emitter { 
    cb : Some(&mut cb)
  };
  
  e.emit();
}
```

The emit() function tries to run the saved callback clojure. But i cannot wrap my head around how to run the callback, since the code produces the following error:

```
  --> src/main.rs:11:15
   |
11 |       let f = self.cb.unwrap();
   |               ^^^^^^^
   |               |
   |               move occurs because `self.cb` has type `Option<&mut dyn FnMut()>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   |               help: consider borrowing the `Option`'s content: `self.cb.as_ref()`
```

Appreciate some help :)

Here is the snippet on replit: https://replit.com/@lutzer/RustEmitterTest

Comment: `self.cb.as_mut().unwrap();` is the solution but you can use `Option::map` instead of `is_some()` and `unwrap()`

Comment: slightly related: cppfaq.rs has advice how to [avoid the observer pattern](https://cppfaq.rs/codebase.html) in Rust

Comment: Also of note is [`Option::take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.take) which takes the contents out of the option and replaces it with `None` (useful if your callback should only be called once).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's going on here is that your line

```rust
let f = self.cb.unwrap();
```

would want to move the closure out of the `Option` enum. This operation *consumes* that enum, which isn't allowed for things that belong to a struct.

Here is a simpler example to show what I mean:

```rust
fn main() {
  let an_option = Some(String::from("Woot!");
  let the_value = an_option.unwrap();
  println!("The value is {}", the_value);

  println!("The option is {:?}", an_option); // error here! Can't use an_option any more!!!
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4a4a3660b68ebada99113db5165b6e76

So if you take ownership of something stored inside the `Some` part of an `Option`, via `unwrap`, then the whole `Option` gets moved out. You can see that in the signature of unwrap:

```rust
pub const fn unwrap(self) -> T
```

Note how it says `self`, and not `&self` or `&mut self`. That means, after calling `unwrap`, that the enum gets consumed and cannot be used any more, unless the value inside the `Some` part can simply be copied (If you replace the `String` in my example with, say, an integer, it will compile without issue).

The comment by [Omer Erden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1601571/%c3%96mer-erden) then explains a way around that: Ask the `Option` to give you a mutable reference instead via `as_mut`.

Or skip all that directly and use the `map` method of option, which you can use to do something if the option is `Some` and just not do anything if it's `None`.

Comment: thanks for the explanation! changing line 11 to the following works: `let f = self.cb.as_mut().unwrap();`

Comment: or as suggested by @lagerbaer with `self.cb.as_mut().map(|f| f() );`